# Not all message read from outlook 2016 by win32com.client

Tags: python, outlook

I've some strange problem with using library win32com.client for reading messages from Outlook 2016. I use code below

Concretely, this code write title folders and subfolders. Then I make .exe by pyinstaller.  Code is working, but on other computers it may not works. Concretely not shows subfolders and not all folders.

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch

outlook = Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
root_folder = outlook.Folders.Item(1)

for folder in root_folder.Folders:
    print(folder.Name)
    for fol in folder.Folders:
        print('-' + fol.Name)
```

Finally I want to load attachments from need subfolders, but this issue disturb me moving on